# Android how to use recyclerview to scroll horizontally in large vertical data set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want to use recylerview to show a large vertical data set with a large amount of data on each row

I am currently using the LinearLayoutManager

### Each row has it's own ViewHolder where I hold a "RowView" object. Each RowView is a fixed width.

```
public class EventsRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private Context                                 mContext;
    private ArrayList<EventsStrip.Item>             mItems;

    public EventsRecylerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventsStrip.Item> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public EventsRecylerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        EventRowView v = new EventRowView(mContext);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        EventsStrip.Item item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.mEventRowView.initItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public EventRowView mEventRowView;

        public int getMeasuredHeight() {
            mEventRowView.measure(0, 0);
            return mEventRowView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        public ViewHolder(EventRowView v) {
            super(v);
            mEventRowView = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my "EventsView" container that has the

```
protected void init(Context context) {
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    if (null == params)
        params = generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    setLayoutParams(params);

    mHeaderScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.headerScrollView);
    mHeaderScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new HeaderScrollViewListener());

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.EventsRecylerView);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerScrollListener());

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
}
```

---

Since each row each wider than the device I would like to enable a horizontal scrollbar so I can scroll sideways to see more data in each row. Currently I am seeing all the data that I would expect to see just clipped at the edge of the screen.

Also, I would like to scroll horizontally programatically. When I call scrollTo(newxvalue, recylerview.getScrollY()) nothing happens. I don't want to scroll to a new position in the adapter list. I want to see more data that is currently "off screen" on the items currently on the screen. I have a static header at the top of the "list" with a horizontal scroll view on it. As the user drags the header I want the list below to stay in sync.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a lot simpler than I thought.

In a list view you will get unpredictable results if you put a list view inside a ScrollView . However in the case I simply put the header view and the RecylerView with a vertical linear layout manager inside of a horizontal ScrollView and it seems to behave as intended (i.e. RecylerView does not have the same limitations as ListView).

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/headerScrollView"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@color/navigation_bar_color"
            android:id="@+id/eventRowLayout"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/EventsRecylerView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/eventRowLayout">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```